# ODE: What method to use?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve this Differential eq. I don't know what method i should use:

$$dy/dx = (y^2 + 1)/(yx^2 + y)$$

I changed it to:

$$ (y^2 + 1)dx -(yx^2 + y)dy = 0$$

Its clearly not 'Exact' and I cannot use separation as is, so I figure I need to use some type of sub?

I tried u = x/y, but no luck.

$$
\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx = \frac{y}{y^2+1}dx
$$

integrate:

$$
arctan(x) = \frac{1}{2}ln|y^2+1|
$$

solve:

e^2arctan(x) = $y^2 + 1$

y = sqrt(e^arctan(x)) +1

Miss something?

Comment: It's definitely separable.

Comment: how do you figure?

Comment: $yx^2+y = y(x^2+1)$

Comment: $yx^2+y$ is not separable EDIT: Dam it...i should have seen that

Comment: Post your answer, ill give you points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange the right-hand side as

$$
\frac{y^2+1}{yx^2+y} = \frac{y^2+1}{y(x^2+1)} = \frac{y^2+1}{y} \cdot \frac{1}{x^2+1},
$$

then separate.

Comment: does my answer look right?

Comment: Don't forget the $+C$, and be careful at the end, it should be $$y = \pm\sqrt{e^{C+2\arctan x}-1}.$$

Comment: math people are crazy with their +C... ok thanks

Comment: Without the $+C$ you'd never be able to satisfy any initial condition but $y(0) = 0$ :)